# Why are wildcards necessary in Java generics?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

If I got it right, the only purpose of Java wildcards is to introduce covariance and contravariance between generic types. I view Java wildcards as a compiler trick to implement these 2 concepts. Am I right or is there more to it?

Answer (score 2):

For the most part that's right, but it's not really a "compiler trick" - much more so a language feature to guarantee *at compile time* that (unchecked casts / warnings aside) you can never end up in a state with inconsistent types at runtime.

The compiler *could* have been easily written to blindly accept such covariant generic code without wildcards just fine - but you'd have no guarantee you wouldn't run into a `ClassCastException` (or a few) later down the line.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are basically right. But I wouldn't call it a *compiler trick* (after all, Java **Generics** are a big compiler trick, nothing else).

Wildcards are a sound type system concept; they guarantee that code you write that does compile and doesn't use casts will succeed at runtime. Thus, wildcards a not a trick; they are a perfectly valid way of expressing *use site variance*.

The only point of criticism is that wildcards to not allow *declaration site variance*, as, for example, C# allows.

Comment: Another thing that confuses me a little is how to read the wildcard correcly. For example, I read this <? extends T> as a 'the set of types that extend T'. I view that as a 'dummy type' used by the compiler. Am I right? Thanks!

Comment: @Kami: Well, you can call it that way. However, the wildcard alone makes no sense. Rather read it as a whole with the type, i.e.: `X<? extends T>` is the set of all generic `X<S>` types whose type parameter `S` is a class that extends `T`.